Can't get DRBD + TLS working
Debian Bookworm 12.5
DRBD and ktls-utils packages from proxmox. Always was fine, until I enabled tls.
ii  drbd-dkms                        9.2.8-2                        all
ii  drbd-reactor                     1.4.0-1                        amd64
ii  drbd-utils                       9.27.0-1                       amd64
ii  ktls-utils                       0.10-6                         amd64

Got drbd on 3 nodes, all in sync, works just fine.
r0 role:Primary
  disk:UpToDate
  slave role:Secondary
    peer-disk:UpToDate
  tiebreaker role:Secondary
    peer-disk:UpToDate

Then I have added net { tls yes; } on all these nodes.
Got this:
dmesg
[  147.759827] drbd r0 slave: conn( Connecting -> NetworkFailure ) [disconnected]
[  147.759848] drbd r0 slave: Terminating sender thread
[  147.759853] drbd r0 slave: Starting sender thread (from drbd_r_r0 [755])
[  147.771131] drbd r0 slave: Connection closed
[  147.771135] drbd r0 slave: helper command: /sbin/drbdadm disconnected
[  147.771587] drbd r0 slave: helper command: /sbin/drbdadm disconnected exit code 0
[  147.771592] drbd r0 slave: conn( NetworkFailure -> Unconnected ) [disconnected]
[  147.977813] drbd r0 tcp:tiebreaker: dtt_send_page: size=80 len=80 sent=-95
[  147.977817] drbd r0 tiebreaker: conn( Connecting -> NetworkFailure ) [disconnected]
[  147.977824] drbd r0 tiebreaker: Terminating sender thread
[  147.977829] drbd r0 tiebreaker: Starting sender thread (from drbd_r_r0 [759])
[  147.987330] drbd r0 tiebreaker: Connection closed
[  147.987335] drbd r0 tiebreaker: helper command: /sbin/drbdadm disconnected
[  147.987744] drbd r0 tiebreaker: helper command: /sbin/drbdadm disconnected exit code 0
[  147.987749] drbd r0 tiebreaker: conn( NetworkFailure -> Unconnected ) [disconnected]
[  148.783089] drbd r0 slave: conn( Unconnected -> Connecting ) [connecting]

ngrep -d any port 7788
interface: any
filter: ( port 7788 ) and (ip || ip6)
####
T 192.168.0.X:52605 -> 192.168.0.Y:7788 [AP] #4
  ....Wf4Q.(.....\.D....x:.0.Y.k 2[..... <SKIPPED MANY LINES>
#####
T 192.168.0.Y:52571 -> 192.168.0.X:7788 [AP] #9
  <SKIPPED MANY LINES>

tcpdump  port 7788
09:11:21.927899 IP 192.168.0.Z.39381 > 192.168.0.Y.7788: Flags [.], ack 2313, win 501, options [nop,nop,TS val 2232236805 ecr 466841460], length 0

journalctl -f -u tlshd
Apr 10 10:18:12 master tlshd[8385]: Handshake with slave ... was successful
Apr 10 10:18:12 master tlshd[8386]: Handshake with tiebreaker ... was successful
^^ fine on all nodes.

On verbose node also this:
DBG<1>././lib/cache_mngt.c:302  nl_cache_mngt_unregister: Unregistered cache operations genl/family

I have certs generated as follows Encrypted Replication With DRBD - LINBIT https://linbit.com/blog/encrypted-replication-with-drbd/ just fixed CN to match hostnames and also added IPs just in case (played with various versions, no luck).
Certs were generated on macos using openssl utility.
-addext "subjectAltName = DNS:$domain, IP:$ip" \
-addext "extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth, clientAuth" \

Got this:
r0 role:Secondary
  disk:UpToDate quorum:no
  slave connection:Connecting
  tiebreaker connection:NetworkFailure

r0 role:Secondary
  disk:UpToDate quorum:no
  slave connection:Unconnected
  tiebreaker connection:Unconnected

I have disabled cram-hmac-alg, data-integrity-alg, shared-secret just in case to keep net section clean with just "tls yes", no luck. It's a simple resource config with 3 nodes and connection-mesh + tls yes.
Is there anything I have forgotten to add to make it all together?
I am running it in local virtual environment, there is no networking issues. Something is wrong with configuration, I have no idea what.
r0.res
resource r0 {
        options {
            auto-promote no;
            on-suspended-primary-outdated force-secondary;
            quorum majority;
            on-no-quorum io-error;
            quorum-minimum-redundancy 2;
        }

        device /dev/drbd0;
        meta-disk        internal;
        disk /dev/sdb1;

        protocol B;

        startup {
                wfc-timeout  15;
                degr-wfc-timeout 60;
        }
        net {
                tls yes;
        }
        on master {
        address 192.168.0.X:7788;
                node-id 0;
        }
        on slave {
        address 192.168.0.Y:7788;
                node-id 1;
        }
        on tiebreaker {
        address 192.168.0.Z:7788;
                node-id 2;
        }
    connection-mesh {
        hosts master slave tiebreaker;
    }
}

More tlshd logs:
pr 11 09:37:19 master tlshd[1008]: Parsing a valid netlink message
Apr 11 09:37:19 master tlshd[1008]: No peer identities found
Apr 11 09:37:19 master tlshd[1008]: No certificates found
Apr 11 09:37:19 master tlshd[1008]: DBG<2>       ././lib/msg.c:572  nlmsg_free: msg 0x5573416ff750: Freed
Apr 11 09:37:19 master tlshd[1008]: DBG<2>       ././lib/msg.c:572  nlmsg_free: msg 0x5573416ff610: Freed
Apr 11 09:37:19 master tlshd[1008]: System config file: /etc/gnutls/config
Apr 11 09:37:19 master tlshd[1008]: Server x.509 truststore is /etc/tlshd.d/myCA.crt
Apr 11 09:37:19 master tlshd[1008]: System trust: Loaded 1 certificate(s).
Apr 11 09:37:19 master tlshd[1008]: Retrieved x.509 certificate from /etc/tlshd.d/master.crt
Apr 11 09:37:19 master tlshd[1008]: Retrieved private key from /etc/tlshd.d/master.key
Apr 11 09:37:19 master tlshd[1008]: gnutls(2): checking 13.02 (GNUTLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384) for compatibility
Apr 11 09:37:19 master tlshd[1008]: gnutls(2): Selected (RSA) cert
Apr 11 09:37:19 master tlshd[1008]: gnutls(2): EXT[0x557341710040]: server generated SECP384R1 shared key
Apr 11 09:37:19 master tlshd[1009]: Server's trusted authorities:
Apr 11 09:37:19 master tlshd[1009]:    [0]: CN=MyCN
Apr 11 09:37:19 master tlshd[1009]: The certificate is trusted.
Apr 11 09:37:19 master tlshd[1009]: The peer offered 1 certificate(s).
Apr 11 09:37:19 master tlshd[1009]: Session description: (TLS1.3)-(ECDHE-SECP384R1)-(RSA-PSS-RSAE-SHA384)-(AES-256-GCM)
Apr 11 09:37:19 master tlshd[1009]: DBG<2>       ././lib/msg.c:277  __nlmsg_alloc: msg 0x5573416ff610: Allocated new message, maxlen=4096
Apr 11 09:37:19 master tlshd[1009]: DBG<2>       ././lib/msg.c:517  nlmsg_put: msg 0x5573416ff610: Added netlink header type=16, flags=0, pid=0, seq=0
Apr 11 09:37:19 master tlshd[1009]: DBG<2>       ././lib/msg.c:424  nlmsg_reserve: msg 0x5573416ff610: Reserved 4 (4) bytes, pad=4, nlmsg_len=20
Apr 11 09:37:19 master tlshd[1009]: DBG<2> ././lib/genl/genl.c:357  genlmsg_put: msg 0x5573416ff610: Added generic netlink header cmd=3 version=1
Apr 11 09:37:19 master tlshd[1009]: DBG<2>      ././lib/attr.c:470  nla_reserve: msg 0x5573416ff610: attr <0x557341703164> 2: Reserved 16 (10) bytes at offset +4 nlmsg_len=36
Apr 11 09:37:19 master tlshd[1009]: DBG<2>      ././lib/attr.c:507  nla_put: msg 0x5573416ff610: attr <0x557341703164> 2: Wrote 10 bytes at offset +4
Apr 11 09:37:19 master tlshd[1009]: DBG<2>       ././lib/msg.c:277  __nlmsg_alloc: msg 0x5573416ff750: Allocated new message, maxlen=164
Apr 11 09:37:19 master tlshd[1009]: DBG<2>       ././lib/msg.c:572  nlmsg_free: msg 0x5573416ff750: Freed
Apr 11 09:37:19 master tlshd[1009]: DBG<2>       ././lib/msg.c:277  __nlmsg_alloc: msg 0x55734170cac0: Allocated new message, maxlen=36
Apr 11 09:37:19 master tlshd[1009]: DBG<2>       ././lib/msg.c:572  nlmsg_free: msg 0x55734170cac0: Freed
Apr 11 09:37:19 master tlshd[1009]: DBG<2>       ././lib/msg.c:572  nlmsg_free: msg 0x5573416ff610: Freed
Apr 11 09:37:19 master tlshd[1009]: DBG<2>       ././lib/msg.c:277  __nlmsg_alloc: msg 0x5573416ff610: Allocated new message, maxlen=4096
Apr 11 09:37:19 master tlshd[1009]: DBG<2>       ././lib/msg.c:517  nlmsg_put: msg 0x5573416ff610: Added netlink header type=32, flags=0, pid=0, seq=0
Apr 11 09:37:19 master tlshd[1009]: DBG<2>       ././lib/msg.c:424  nlmsg_reserve: msg 0x5573416ff610: Reserved 4 (4) bytes, pad=4, nlmsg_len=20
Apr 11 09:37:19 master tlshd[1009]: DBG<2> ././lib/genl/genl.c:357  genlmsg_put: msg 0x5573416ff610: Added generic netlink header cmd=3 version=0
Apr 11 09:37:19 master tlshd[1009]: DBG<2>      ././lib/attr.c:470  nla_reserve: msg 0x5573416ff610: attr <0x557341703164> 1: Reserved 8 (4) bytes at offset +4 nlmsg_len=28
Apr 11 09:37:19 master tlshd[1009]: DBG<2>      ././lib/attr.c:507  nla_put: msg 0x5573416ff610: attr <0x557341703164> 1: Wrote 4 bytes at offset +4
Apr 11 09:37:19 master tlshd[1009]: DBG<2>      ././lib/attr.c:470  nla_reserve: msg 0x5573416ff610: attr <0x55734170316c> 2: Reserved 8 (4) bytes at offset +12 nlmsg_len=36
Apr 11 09:37:19 master tlshd[1009]: DBG<2>      ././lib/attr.c:507  nla_put: msg 0x5573416ff610: attr <0x55734170316c> 2: Wrote 4 bytes at offset +12
Apr 11 09:37:19 master tlshd[1009]: DBG<2>      ././lib/attr.c:470  nla_reserve: msg 0x5573416ff610: attr <0x557341703174> 3: Reserved 8 (4) bytes at offset +20 nlmsg_len=44
Apr 11 09:37:19 master tlshd[1009]: DBG<2>      ././lib/attr.c:507  nla_put: msg 0x5573416ff610: attr <0x557341703174> 3: Wrote 4 bytes at offset +20
Apr 11 09:37:19 master tlshd[1009]: DBG<2>       ././lib/msg.c:572  nlmsg_free: msg 0x5573416ff610: Freed
Apr 11 09:37:19 master tlshd[1009]: Handshake with slave (192.168.0.Y) was successful
Apr 11 09:37:19 master tlshd[1009]: DBG<1>././lib/cache_mngt.c:302  nl_cache_mngt_unregister: Unregistered cache operations genl/family


Okay, it was very deceptive log messages from tlshd which leads to thinking something is wrong with drbd but in fact it was Kernel version. I have installed 6.6.13 from Debian Backports repository and it works now.

nice to hear. please remind to accept your answer after 24 hours else we will be reminded until the end of the universe to solve this problem.
